# Strange problem with ubuntu while minimizing the window

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

I am using ubuntu 10.04. Yesterday i shut down my system in a proper working state. And this morning when i started my system i got this problem.
When i minimize any window it doesnt show in the bottom panel. for switching i have to use alt+tab key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

right click on the panel. click on add to panel and then add "switch window " :-)

Answer (score 1):

To check if this is a bug or a configuration error, you should move the following configuration folders. This will cause Gnome to regenerate configurations as if this was the first time you logged-in

```
mv .gnome .gnome-bk
mv .gnome2 .gnome2-bk
mv .gnome2_private .gnome2_private-bk
mv .gconf .gconfig-bk
mv .gconfd .gconfd-bk
mv .metacity .metacity-bk
```

If your issue goes away, it maybe related to an upgrade of gnome or a configuration error. 
If your issue continues, seek support in ways suggested on ubuntu's website.

To delete old configurations

```
rm -rf .*-bk
```

Useful Link:
[How to reset ubuntu gnome settings to defaults without reinstalling](http://linuxfud.wordpress.com/2007/02/14/how-to-reset-ubuntugnome-settings-to-defaults-without-re-installing/)

Comment: sorry didnt worked.

Comment: You will have to provide more information, regarding 'what didn't work'. Your issue still continued after removing or moving previous configurations?